# How to run latex2wp

Tags: html, latex2html

I do wonder if this is the appropriate place to ask but I have been searching for a bit without any success about how to run the latex2wp that is used in the Terry Tao's Wordpress. It would be greatly appreciated if anyone with experience of using this can advise me.

In particular, I am rather confused about this line in the ReadMe after the download. "In the directory in which latex2wp.py and your tex file are both present, type python latex2wp.py yourlatexfile.tex this will produce a file called yourlatexfile.html whichis ready to be cut and pasted into WordPress."

I presumed this is something I type into the command prompt after getting the correct directory and I alter the name of the tex file to an appropriate one.

Apologies but I have not used Python so sorry if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Your presumption is correct. Did you try it?

Comment: I did. I typed in "cd" and then the appropriate file directory where I copied the latex2wp files and then typed "python latex2wp.py yourlatexfile.tex " where I changed youlatexfile to the corresponding name of the Tex file.

Comment: Cool then, that should work (if you have python installed and available in the commandline). If everything has gone correctly, it would have produced a .html file in the same directory. You can open that file in any plain text editor (e.g. Notepad) and paste the contents into your WordPress blog.

Comment: Do I need to have Python installed in the same directory as the tex file that I want to convert in? I am still unable to get any html file

Comment: It will help if you say (and read) what happens when you run that command: what gets printed at the command prompt?

Comment: I get the "Bad command or file name" error.

Comment: Hard to tell from that… General advice: when asking questions on the internet like this, you will get much better help if you provide as much information as possible, about every step you did, and more importantly, detailed and complete information about all the error messages and results you got. For example, instead of saying “Bad command or file name”, you could take screenshot(s) of your entire interaction in the command prompt (or copy the text), and include it in the question. (If you had done this at the very first step, you might have also saved yourself a few hours of back-and-forth.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61841/discussion-between-daruma-and-shreevatsar).